# What is the correct way to memoize this useEffect dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, scroll, react-usememo

I use `useEffect` to listen for a change in `location.pathname` to auto-scroll back to the top of the page (router) when the route changes. As I have a page transition (that takes `pageTransitionTime * 1000` seconds), I use a timer that waits for the page transition animation to occur before the reset takes place. However, on the first load/mount of the router (after a loading page), I **do NOT** want to wait for the animation as there is no page animation.

Observe the code below, which works exactly as intended:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0,0)
    }, firstVisit.app ? 0 : pageTransitionTime * 1000 )
    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
}, [location.pathname, pageTransitionTime])
```

The error I face here is that `firstVisit.app` isn't in the dependency array. I get this error on Terminal:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'firstVisit.app'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

`firstVisit.app` is a global redux variable that is updated in the same React component by another `useEffect`, setting it to `false` as soon as the router is mounted (this `useEffect` has no dependency array, so it achieves it purpose instantly).

```
// UPON FIRST MOUNT, SET firstVisit.app TO FALSE
useEffect(() => {
    if (firstVisit.app) {
        dispatch(setFirstVisit({
            ...firstVisit,
            app: false
        }))
    }
})
```

The problem is, when I include `firstVisit.app` in the dependency array in the first `useEffect`, the page will auto-reset scroll to (0,0) after pageTransitionTime, affecting the UX.

A bit of Googling lead me to find that I may need to memoize `firstVisit.app` but I'm not entirely sure how or the logic behind doing so?

Comment: IMO exhaustive-deps sometimes just doesn't make sense with `useEffect` (unlike other hooks). This might be a time to ignore the linter.

Answer (score -2):

React's log message tried to say that in your first `useEffect` hook callback function body you used some value that excluded in the list of dependencies. That's correct, please refer: [useEffect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

> The array of dependencies is not passed as arguments to the effect
> function. Conceptually, though, that’s what they represent: every
> value referenced inside the effect function should also appear in the
> dependencies array. In the future, a sufficiently advanced compiler
> could create this array automatically.

> We recommend using the exhaustive-deps rule as part of our
> eslint-plugin-react-hooks package. It warns when dependencies are
> specified incorrectly and suggests a fix.

So, add to the second array parameter of `useEffect` `firstVisit.app`, and then check whether this warning/error is gone or not.

Also, you don't need to memoize primitive values, like `boolean` values (true/false), React is smart enough to not run your callback function again, when your boolean dependency hasn't changed after re-rendering.

[Edit]

If you want to run some logic in `useEffect` except initial render, i.e. to skip the first time render, you can use:

```
const isMounted = useRef(false);
    
useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
       doYourTransition();
    } else {
       isMounted.current = true;
    }
}, [deps]);
```

More complicated one with custom hook, but can be helpful based on your needs and wishes:

```
const useEffectAfterMount = (cb, deps) => {
    const isMounted = useRef(false);
        
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
           cb();
        } else {
          isMounted.current = true;
        }
    }, deps);
}
    
useEffectAfterMount(() => {
   // the logic here runs always, but not on initial render
}, [firstVisit.app]);
```

I think, you got the idea. Of course, you can move these hooks into a separate file and to reuse them across the project and minimize the amount of code in your current component as well.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I may have missed some context in my question. If I add `firstVisit.app` to the dependency array, the error *does* go away, however my page doesn't behave as intended; it reloads after `pageTransitionTime * 1000` because the value of `firstVisit.app` actually changes when that component mounts for the first time. I don't want it to re-render just that first time...

Comment: @singing , ok, I got you. I will edit my answer to add the code that can help you in this case.